# angular material mat-slide-toggle inside a mat-form-field

Tags: angular, angular-material

If I have a mat-slide-toggle inside a mat-form-field I get the error:

> Error: mat-form-field must contain a MatFormFieldControl

I want my mat-slide-toggle inside my mat-form-field so i can get the styling. Any ideas why i get this error?
Is a mat-slide-toggle not a mat-form-field???

Here is an example of what I currently have:

```
<mat-form-field fxFlexFill *ngSwitchCase="'mat-slide-toggle'">
    <mat-slide-toggle>{{el.text}}</mat-slide-toggle>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: [**This error occurs when you have not added a form field control to your form field. If your form field contains a native <input> or <textarea> element, make sure you've added the matInput directive to it and have imported MatInputModule.**](https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/overview)

Comment: ouch, So it sounds like a mat-slide-toggle may not be placed inside of a mat-form-field... that isn't great.

Comment: That stackblitz shows the slider outside of the mat-form-field section

Comment: @SouravDutta none of your examples answer the op's question. Read it more carefully please.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I present two slightly different hacks with **no underline** based upon multiple answers

## Label above with extended clickable white space, uses css

[image]

```html
<mat-form-field floatLabel="always" appearance="none">
  <mat-label>Override Speed</mat-label>
  <mat-slide-toggle [(ngModel)]="Override"><span class="text-invisible">Override Speed</span></mat-slide-toggle>
  <textarea matInput hidden></textarea>
</mat-form-field>
```

```css
.text-invisible {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

## Label to the right, no css

[image]

```html
<mat-form-field floatLabel="always" appearance="none">
  <mat-slide-toggle [(ngModel)]="Override">Override Speed</mat-slide-toggle>
  <textarea matInput hidden></textarea>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: That is exactly what i was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: I got: Type '"none"' is not assignable to type 'MatFormFieldAppearance'.

Comment: I have not seen this module as of yet. I would verify the app.module file contains the right imports. Possibly share your code or ask a new question and share he link to it here.

Comment: Minor notes from a few years later - only making the text invisible still leaves the `label` target accessible, so you've got a pointer cursor active in a whitespace area. I replaced the text-opacity with `display: none`. As others mentioned, "none" is not an assignable appearance in material (at least not in 2022). I found that removing the appearance attribute altogether fixed that.

Comment: Up from Angular v15.x.x this is not longer possible as `appearance="none"` is not a valid value

Comment: Angular v15.x.x you can use 'display': 'none' <textarea matInput [ngStyle]="{'display':'none'}"></textarea>

Answer (score 8):

You can, however, put a hidden text field inside the mat-form-field to satisfy the requirement and, if necessary, bind all the values together if what you want is to get the same look as the other fields.

```
<mat-form-field floatLabel="always">
        <mat-label>Label</mat-label>
        <mat-slide-toggle>Raw</mat-slide-toggle>
        <textarea matInput hidden></textarea>
    </mat-form-field>
```

Comment: How do you get rid of the underline when doing this?

Comment: @Robert add `appearance="none"` to the `<mat-form-field>`

Comment: @Robert I used 
`.mat-form-field-underline {
  display: none;
}`

Comment: @Wungsow solution works onyl because appearance has not none option. May I suggest to use class name for matform-field and add ::ng-deep to selector with spesific class name to not broke other places.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding a hidden input field

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-slide-toggle class="example-margin" [color]="color" [checked]="checked"
    [disabled]="disabled">
    Cumulative
  </mat-slide-toggle>
  <input matInput #value hidden />
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: how do you get rid of the underline when doing this?

Comment: @Robert either via css, or by setting the `[appearance]` input of the form field to a invalid value, like `<mat-form-field class="w100p" [appearance]="'nope'">`. This way, the css styles of the underline will not be applied (as shown in the [source](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/5715a9c2f45bc998140571f39ebf06373661b2e2/src/material/form-field/form-field.ts#L117]))

Answer (score 1):

According to official documentation you can't do this ([link](https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/overview)).

> The following Angular Material components are designed to work inside
>   a `<mat-form-field>`:
>
> - `<input matNativeControl>` & `<textarea matNativeControl>`
> - `<select matNativeControl>`
> - `<mat-select>`
> - `<mat-chip-list>`

Comment: check this link out under Use with @angular/forms: https://material.angular.io/components/slide-toggle/overview

Comment: @BilalDjaghout `<mat-form-field>` works with text fields. `<mat-slide-toggle>` is not a text field.

Answer (score -3):

Unfortunately Mat-Form-Fields do not work/function when a mat-slide toggle is inside of them. I had to find this out the hard way myself.

Try this instead:

```
<div fxFlexFill *ngSwitchCase="'mat-slide-toggle'">
    <mat-slide-toggle>{{el.text}}</mat-slide-toggle>
</div>
```

Comment: this isnt remotely true, you can add a hidden input field

    `<input matInput #value hidden />`